# Unable to debug android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging

I have app in eclipse that was running well lately

Now it suddenly stops. 
After I hit debug code runs and there is breakpoint in it.

From there on I am unable to debug and go step by step through the code because ther is no pointer showing me current line code at all.
Als o I noticed that all buttons in Run menu are grayed out (Terminate, REsume, Disconnect all of them)

So the only way to stop program running is to shut down eclipse

Any ideas ?

@Tobia
yes i saw the red button but unfortunatelly that did not helped. eclipse is such crap that can not be fixed with 1 red button. i had to downoad 32bit version and now it looks like it is working. 2nd issue now i have: THE ONLY way i ca nstart this crap app is to use -clean -clearPersistedState switches. ANYONE KNOWS IF THIS ECLIPSE CAN RUN NORMALY ?

Comment: Many a times Eclipse has this issue.You can restart the eclipse or press the red button on your status bar of eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just hit the red square on the top of the menu. Or also you can go to your device and stop your application, from settings->apps->yourapp->force stop or something like.

[image]

Comment: did you select on debug view, the runing process and the hit the red button?